Fake set inclusion proof involving closure
I am currently studying general topology using the Italian book "Topologia", by Marco Manetti (Springer) and faced one exercise (namely $3.16$) which asks to find the mistake(s) in the following fake proof that $$\overline{\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_{i}} \subset \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} \overline {A_{i}}.$$
Firstly, while the converse statement holds, let me point out that this claim is in fact false: for example, consider $I = \mathbb{N}$ and $A_i = \left[\frac{1}{i}, 1-\frac{1}{i}\right]$. Then $\overline {A_{i}} = A_{i}$, so $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} \overline {A_{i}} = \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_{i} = \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left[\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}\right] = (0,1)$, but $\overline{\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_{i}} = \overline{\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left[\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}\right]} = \overline{(0,1)} = [0,1].$
The "proof" is the following: let $x \in \overline{\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_{i}}.$ Then every neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ intersects $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_{i}.$ Therefore, every neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ intersects some $A_{i_0}$, so $x \in \overline{A_{i_0}}$ and thus $x \in \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} \overline{A_i}.$
I think that the mistake relies on the fact that $i_0$ depends on the neighbourhood. In fact, $x \in \overline{A_{i_0}}$ by definition means that $U$ intersects $A_{i_0}\forall U$ neighborhood of $x$, but I only know that $V$ does. I am not sure that my intuition is correct though, so any help and formal description of the mistake(s) would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT: it looks like my intuition works in this example. For every neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ there exists some $n_V \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $V \cap \left[\frac{1}{n_V}, 1-\frac{1}{n_V}\right] \neq \emptyset$ - in my example $A_{i_0}$ would be $\left[\frac{1}{n_V}, 1-\frac{1}{n_V}\right]$. However, if I choose $x=0$ and $U=\left(-\frac{1}{n_V}, \frac{1}{n_V}\right)$, then $U \cap A_{i_0}=\emptyset.$

Have you checked your intuition against your example?

I could be wrong but I'm not sure about "Then every neighborhood $V$ of $x$ intersects $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i$", wouldn't it be possible for $x$ to not be a limit point of $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i$ even if $x \in \overline{\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_{i}}$?

@BrianMoehring thanks for asking. Please check my edit.

@powerline by definition $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if and only if $x \in \overline{A}$. Maybe you know another definition of limit point but this one is equivalent

@DavideMasi I wasn't aware of that definition. to make clear, the motivation for my comment was that $\overline A = A \cup A'$, where $A'$ is the set of its limit points, so I thought $x \in \overline A \nRightarrow x \in A'$. but given that definition, this reasoning must be wrong somewhere

@powerline I'm rusty on my terminology.  I would guess $x \in A'$ if and only if every punctured neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$.  The definition of $\bar{A}$ is the same but removes "punctured".  This means, yes, $A'$ isn't $\bar{A}$, but I don't see how $A'$ appears in the problem.

@BrianMoehring I guess I wrongly assumed it was implied in the false proof that $x$ is a limit point of $\bigcup_{i \in I}A_i$. and for that to be implied truly it had to be said “punctured neighbourhood V”  I guess. sorry for the confusion

Your intuition is correct.
To be precise, the proof is right up to and including "therefore, every neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ intersects some $A_{i_0}$" but "so $x \in \overline{A_{i_0}}$ and thus $x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} \overline{A_i}$" doesn't follow: $i_0$ depends on the chosen neighborhood $V$, so there's no reason to assume that another neighborhood $V'$ of $x$ intersects $A_{i_0}$, too; it will certainly intersect some $A_{i_1}$, but we need not have $i_0 = i_1$. But then there's of course no reason to expect that $x \in \overline{A_{i_0}}$ (or any other $\overline{A_i}$), so the conclusion is invalid.
...but I'm not telling you anything new here: Your worked out example already clearly demonstrates this.
